# Converting a UINT32 value into a UINT8 array[4]

Tags: c++, c, endianness

My question is how do you convert a UINT32 value to a UINT8 array[4] (C/C++) preferably in a manner independent of endianness? Additionally, how would you reconstruct the UINT32 value from the UINT8 array[4], to get back to where you started?

Comment: How do you want to do the conversion? Big-endian or little-endian? Specifically: If your input is 0x12345678, do you want array[0] to be 0x12 or 0x78? You have to decide this for yourself. Then we can help you.

Answer (score 40):

You haven't really said what you mean by *independent of endianness* - it's unclear since the byte array must have *some* endianness.   That said, *one* of the below must answer your requirements:

Given `UINT32 v` and `UINT8 a[4]`:

### "Host" endian

(use the machine's native byte order):

```
UINT8 *vp = (UINT8 *)&v;
a[0] = vp[0];
a[1] = vp[1];
a[2] = vp[2];
a[3] = vp[3];
```

or:

```
memcpy(a, &v, sizeof(v));
```

or:

```
*(UINT32 *)a = v;
```

### Big endian

(aka "network order"):

```
a[0] = v >> 24;
a[1] = v >> 16;
a[2] = v >>  8;
a[3] = v;
```

### Little endian

```
a[0] = v;
a[1] = v >>  8;
a[2] = v >> 16;
a[3] = v >> 24;
```

Comment: Do you have a solution for move semantics? Say you want to move the value of v to the byte array without copying v.

Comment: @jiggunjer that makes no sense.  Primitive values can't get "moved" like that.

Comment: @jiggunjer Yes.  If you're talking about C++11 "move semantics" there's nothing to "move" in a 32-bit variable.

Comment: I realise this is an old answer (it got liked to by an EE.SE question). But `*(UINT32 *)a = v;` is a very dangerous assumption - if `a` is not initialised aligned to a `UINT32` word boundary this will likely cause an unaligned access error.

Answer (score 15):

E.g. like this:

```
UINT32 value;
UINT8 result[4];

result[0] = (value & 0x000000ff);
result[1] = (value & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
result[2] = (value & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
result[3] = (value & 0xff000000) >> 24;
```

**Edit:** added parenthesis (>> seems to have higher precedence than &)

Comment: The masks for `result[0]` and `result[3]` do not seem strictly necessary.

Comment: Remove the &'s. They're useless and a bad compiler might not eliminate them. Simply `result[0]=value; result[1]=value>>8; ...` is all you need.

Comment: @R.: I disagree. They express the symmetry (I normally have a `>> 0` for exactly this purpose), and it would have to be a pretty terrible compiler that wouldn't optimise them away.

Comment: Whatever the aesthetic merits of the `&` operators, the fact is that they kill the code. `>>` has higher precedence than `&`.

Comment: @TonyK is exactly right; this is incorrect because of operator precedence.  The masks are unnecessary anyway -- all you need are the shifts.

Comment: @R.: Actually, I take that back.  I overlooked the fact that we're converting to `uint8`, so of course, all masks are unnecessary, as @Stephen points out.

Comment: To all: I agree with the precedence problem.  I forgot the parenthesis (should have checked this).  Sorry for that.

Comment: And regarding the use of &: You don't only write code for the compiler.  You also write code for the one reading the code after you.  In my opinion, adding & makes it clear that you take this specific byte, and you don't rely on any behind-your-back truncation.  I still think that the compiler is smarter than the one reading the code.  So don't make the code readable for the compiler; make it readable for the reader.

Comment: You should note that this is little endian.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to code it yourself, you can use the C library function [htonl()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to convert the 32-bit int to network byte order. There is also the function [ntohl()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to convert them back to host order.

Once they're in network byte order, it's simply a matter of accessing the int/long as a byte array.

All in all that's are probably the most portable and tested way of achieving your goal.

Answer (score 2):

One could also do it with pointers. (This is little endian, but if you use the same reconstruction method it won't matter)

```
uint32 in = 0x12345678;
uint8 out[4];
*(uint32*)&out = in;
```

This assigns the value of the uint32 to the 4 bytes after the memory address of the uint8, doing exactly what you need.

To go the other way:

```
uint8 in[4] = {0x78, 0x56, 0x34, 0x12};
uint32 out;
out = *(uint32*)&in
```

Comment: I realise this is an old answer (it got liked to by an EE.SE question). But `*(uint32*)&out = in;` is a very dangerous assumption - if `a` is not initialised aligned to a `uint32` word boundary this will likely cause an unaligned access error on some processors.

Answer (score -4):

use a Union consisting of an Array with 4 time uint8
and an uint32.

So it sorts automatically by c inherent pointer Magic (Arrays are pointers to start of array)