# How to uint32 to unsigned char array

Tags: c, arrays, char, unsigned, uint32

I have 8 uint32 elements and i want to break each uint32 into 4 uint8 then add all uint8 beside each others as unsigned chars in the array , how can i do that ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting a UINT32 value into a UINT8 array\[4\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499183/converting-a-uint32-value-into-a-uint8-array4)

Comment: How do you mean "add all uint8 beside each others"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the power of **union** for this

```
union value
{
   uint32 number;

   struct bytes
   {
       uint8 bytevalue[4];
   };
};
```

Comment: I agree with using a union, but that inner struct is useless cruft. You can just write `union value { uint32_t quad; uint8_t bytes[4]; };`.

Comment: The downside with union is that the code turns endian-dependent, you can't specify the order of the 4 individual bytes. If portability is important, then you can't use union.

Answer (score 1):

```
UINT32 value;
UINT8 byteval[4];

for(int i = 0 < 4; i++)
    byteval[i] = value >> (i*8);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Structure & Union in combination.

```
    typedef struct
{
    uint32 ArrayOf32Bit[8];
}Arrayof32bitVar_t;

typedef union
{
    Arrayof32bitVar_t Var8int32;
    uint8             Array8char[8*4]; // instead use macro
}tydefUnion_t;

func_add
{
    int i
    tydefUnion_t a; // 

    /*Here update variable a.Var8int32.ArrayOf32Bit*/

    int addResult = 0; 
    for(i;i<(8*4);i++)
    {
        addResult += a.Array8char[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: your second typedef in incomplete.